# What's the difference between the `php71` and `php71w` in the yum repos?

Tags: yum, php, repository

I use `yum list *php71*`, there shows:

```
...
php71-php-zstd.x86_64                                                            0.4.14-1.el7.remi                                                             remi-safe 
php71-scldevel.x86_64                                                            1.0-1.el7.remi                                                                remi-safe 
php71-uwsgi-plugin-php.x86_64                                                    2.0.17.1-2.el7.remi                                                           remi-safe 
php71-zephir.noarch                                                              0.10.10-1.el7.remi                                                            remi-safe 
php71-zephir-parser.x86_64                                                       0.9.11-1.el7.remi                                                             remi-safe 
php71w-bcmath.x86_64                                                             7.1.21-1.w6                                                                   webtatic  
php71w-cli.x86_64                                                                7.1.21-1.w6                                                                   webtatic  
php71w-common.x86_64     
...
```

I see there are `php71-*` and `php71w-*`, so what's the difference between them?

Comment: They're probably from different repos (remi and webtatic?), `yum info php71w-common` will show you what repo it's from.

Comment: Related on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/944953/what-does-the-w-in-yum-install-y-php56w-stand-for